# How to bootstrap a docker container?

Tags: docker

I created a docker image with pre-installed packages in it (apache, mysql, memcached, solr, etc). Now I want to run a command in a container made from this image, and this command relies on all my packages. I want to have all of them started when I start a new container.

I tried to use `/sbin/init`, but it [doesn't work](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/223) in docker.

Answer (score 1):

The general opinion is to use a process manager to do this. I wont go into the details here, since I wrote a blog on that: http://blog.trifork.com/2014/03/11/using-supervisor-with-docker-to-manage-processes-supporting-image-inheritance/

Note that another rather general opinion is to split your containers. MySQL generally is on a different container, but you can try to get that to work later on as well of course :)

Answer (score 1):

I see that this is an old topic, however, for someone who just came across it - [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) can be used to connect multiple containers, so most of the processes can be split up in different containers. Furthermore, as mentioned earlier, different process managers can be used in order to run processes simultaneously and the one that I would like to mention is [Chaperone](http://garywiz.github.io/chaperone/index.html). I find it really easy to use and slightly better than supervisor!

Answer (score 0):

docker compose and docker sync  ->  You can not go wrong applying this concept.

-Glynn